# Using mutate to create new category conditional on dynamically named columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new column `category` based on the values of another set of columns. However, I want to dynamically select the columns on which to condition instead of hard coding the column names. If possible, I'd like to stay within the tidyverse.

Here's my minimally reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(user = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
       jan = c(200, 500, 0, 20, 0),
       feb = c(50, 10, 0, 0, 50),
       mar = c(10, 100, 20, 0, 0),
       apr = c(500, 10, 0, 20, 0))
```

The `category` column should contain the value 'stable' if the row has a non-zero value in each of the last 3 months. This code does what I want:

```
df %>%
  mutate(category = if_else(feb != 0 & mar != 0 & apr != 0, "stable", NA_character_))
```

However, if I would like to run this code on a monthly basis (after adding a new month's data), I will have constantly update it to reference the latest 3 months' column names.

Is there a way I can do this dynamically? I tried using the column positions with `last_col(offset = 2:0)` but without success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In `dplyr` you might have to do something like: `name_vec <- tail(names(df),3)` `df %>%
  mutate(category = if_else(!!sym(name_vec[1])!= 0 & !!sym(name_vec[2]) != 0 & !!sym(name_vec[3]) != 0, "stable", NA_character_))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential logic is already captured in Ronak Shah's answer, but that could be one of possible `dplyr` ways:

```
n <- 3

df %>%
  mutate(
    category = ifelse(
      rowSums(select(., last_col(offset = 0:(n-1))) == 0) > 0, 
      NA_character_, 
      "stable")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks arg0naut91! Just out of curiosity, why is the `.` required inside the select call fed to rowSums?

Comment: Removing it will fail - `rowSums` requires an array, and you need to produce it with a normal `select` statement as otherwise it won't work within `mutate`.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be simple with base R, you can do

```
n <- 3
df$category <- c(NA, "stable")[(rowSums(df[tail(names(df), n)] != 0) == n) + 1]

#  user    jan   feb   mar   apr category
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
#1 A       200    50    10   500 stable  
#2 B       500    10   100    10 stable  
#3 C         0     0    20     0 NA      
#4 D        20     0     0    20 NA      
#5 E         0    50     0     0 NA
```

Comment: Using rowSums with the logical vector didn't occur to me but it's an elegant way to get the desired output. My actual code has a bunch of case_when statements of which this is one of the cases, so a dplyr-based solution will be easier to integrate (which is why I accepted the answer provided by @arg0naut91). However, thanks a lot for coming up with the logic required to achieve this!